# Almacenar una subconsulta en una variable

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de almacenar en una variable una subconsulta para luego introducirla en otra consulta. El código que tengo es este:

```
$anu = "(SELECT DISTINCT Prod_Anun FROM productos where Prod_Anun = 'Particular')";

$consulta="SELECT * 
           FROM productos
           WHERE Prod_Tit LIKE '%$bus%'
           AND Prod_Anun = '$anu'";
```

Seguidamente hago la  conexión con la BDD y todo el proceso de mostrar los datos por pantalla el cual no funciona porque supongo que el método de pasar la subconsulta es incorrecto.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás haciendo en buenas cuentas es

```
$consulta="SELECT * 
           FROM productos
           WHERE Prod_Tit LIKE '%$bus%'
           AND Prod_Anun = '(SELECT DISTINCT Prod_Anun FROM productos where Prod_Anun = 'Particular')'";
```

Y eso sintácticamente no tiene ningún sentido. Lo que realmente quieres hacer es

```
$consulta="SELECT * 
           FROM productos
           WHERE Prod_Tit LIKE '%$bus%'
           AND Prod_Anun IN (SELECT DISTINCT Prod_Anun FROM productos where Prod_Anun = 'Particular')";
```

Pero como el SELECT DISTINCT es un subset del SELECT, en realidad lo que realmente-realmente quieres hacer es

```
$consulta="SELECT * 
           FROM productos
           WHERE Prod_Tit LIKE '%$bus%'
           AND Prod_Anun IN (SELECT Prod_Anun FROM productos where Prod_Anun = 'Particular')";
```

Comment: Pero lo que necesito es un método para introducir la subconsulta de $anu puesto que dependiendo de lo que se haga previamente en un formulario esta variable podría tomar un valor u otro. Entonces, agradezco que me aclares el modo correcto de hacer la consulta, pero la cuestión de mi problema es si se puede insertar la subconsulta de la variable directamente en la variable, no se si me explico

Comment: Sí se puede. Sin las comillas y con el operador IN. Pero es una mala práctica. Si completas tu pregunta explicando cómo le das forma a la subconsulta, podríamos ayudarte mejor.